# USE % WILD IN WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, sql-like

I have a record in my MySQL database which is a varchar type for e.g

```
 john;john;john;jack;jack;steve;steve
```

I am running a query to fetch this record, say the column name is **NAME** and **table** name is **DATA**. so my query is .........

```
SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE NAME LIKE '%john;jack;steve%'
```

But this query isn't fetching any record

Tell me any possible way to fetch this particular record through this **'%john;jack;steve%'**

Comment: The string `john;john;john;jack;jack;steve;steve` does not contain the substring `john;jack;steve` so that's why you're not seeing results.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE NAME LIKE '%john;jack;jack;steve%' ` would find a match.

Comment: what if i have to fetch that particular using this sub-string only i.e john;jack;steve ....? is there any way for doing that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table data doesn't match what you are searching for.

What you can do is, separate each name as different conditions:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DATA 
WHERE NAME LIKE '%john%'
   AND NAME LIKE '%jack%'
   AND NAME LIKE '%steve%'
```